# What is the cargo capacity of a Boeing 737-200/-300?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing-737, commercial-operations, payload

I would like to know the maximum commercial load of a cargo aircraft B737-200 & 300.

Comment: @ymb1 It's a different aircraft and the title doesn't match the question. I fixed it.

Comment: @Pilothead - rolled it back, answer is applicable to any plane by a simple search for the manufacturer as the answer shows. Otherwise expect this question being asked for every type.

Comment: @ymb1 That is probably best.

Comment: Weight, size or volume?